# Get substring from Oracle message error

Tags: regex

How can I retrieve from this
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00904: "REPLAC": invalid identifier

that what goes from ORA and its colon, so for this example
"REPLAC": invalid identifier

Comment: Well it looks like you've misspelled `REPLACE` for `REPLAC` somewhere in your query.

Comment: this is for python

Comment: i need a regex for purpose

Answer (score 0):

[Test working here](https://regex101.com/r/GVfwjp/1/)  `.*ORA[\d\w\-]*\:(.*)` shall get you the error

Comment: I need - "REPLAC": invalid identifier

Comment: I've fixed the regex please check

Comment: I've fixed the minor issue now it should work perfectly for your case. You can check on the link provided. @ElessarElfstone